# Creating Dot Leaders for Restaurant Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a restaurant menu with dot leaders and I'm having trouble with this.

The format I'm looking for is the picture posted below.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="dotted">
                        <ol>
                          <li>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                                <p><span>Test 2</span><span class="price">$3.50(2) - $6.50(4)</span></p>
                            </li>   
                        </ol>
                        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
p { margin: 0 0 -5px 0; }

li { 
    width: 100&#37;;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; 
    list-style-type:none
}

span { 
    position: relative; 
    bottom: -1px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    background: #FFF;     
}

span.price { 
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; bottom: -6px;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: This is from 2009, but it does what you want: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-menu-list-design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the first line of each group in a div that you make a flex container and use the following settings. The second line (ingredients) is outside of that container and can be a simple paragraph or DIV that has some bottom margin.

```css
.linewrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.middle {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.ingredients {
  color: #bbb;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="linewrapper">
  <div>
    QUAIL
  </div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div>
     9.9
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ingredients">
  stuff, stuff, stuff...
</div>
<div class="linewrapper">
  <div>
    SEA TROUT
  </div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div>
     26.9
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ingredients">
  stuff, stuff, stuff...
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect for me, but I have a slight problem. 

http://pasteboard.co/rjti1WzeV.png

The ingredients are centered to the middle, and I'm trying to push it to the left of the screen.

Comment: seems like you have some other element around it that has `text-align: center`  (or something similar)

Comment: I do have text-align: center on other parts of the divs seperate to this one. Is it possible that it can affect this portion of this div ?

Comment: well, then just add `text-align: left;` to `.ingredients`

Comment: Thank you, everything is perfect now !

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element with a dashed (or dotted or whatever) border to draw the dots and position it behind the text using `z-index` and give the text a background color so that the dots don't bleed through.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  align-items: baseline;
}
li:before {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #333;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 .5em
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Quail</span> <span>9.9</span></li>
  <li><span>Quail</span> <span>9.9</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background: #fff;
}
.wrapper{
  width:500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;

}
span{
  float: right;
}

span, strong{
  position:relative;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 1px;
}

.description{
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
  <li><div class="line"><strong>My product</strong><span>Price</span></div><div class="description">My description</div></li>
   <li><div class="line"><strong>My product</strong><span>Price</span></div><div class="description">My description</div></li>
    <li><div class="line"><strong>My product</strong><span>Price</span></div><div class="description">My description</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```